# Nutanix AMD-V - hardware assisted virtualisation

Tags: nutanix

Does anyone have any clarify on whether Nutanix official supports AMD-V. AMD's version of Hardware assisted virtualisation and if there are any constraints.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't...

https://www.nutanix.com/products/hardware-platforms/

Good news: You can migrate VMs from AMD to Intel "patching" them in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Nutanix now does support AMD Epyc processors in partnership with HPE ProLiant DX servers!
https://www.nutanix.com/hpe/amd